# Can a sun tunnel be installed with a 15 to 20 degree angle in it?

Tags: lighting

Can a sun tunnel be installed with a 15 to 20 degree angle in it? If so, how would it affect the amount of light it transfers into the room?

Comment: What does the manufacturer's web site say? From my past research they are usually capable of being bent, but the degree of bend may vary from manufacturer to manufacturer.

Comment: Are you referring to a bend in the pipe? Or just an angled installation?

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not they can be bent, and the degree to which they can be bent, depends on the manufacturer.

The amount of light **will** be impacted, but the question is by how much. Light is lost the more reflections required to reach the diffuser.

I would say you don't need to worry to much if you have one bend. Where it will get bad is if you have multiple bends and (in the case of flexible-reflector units) if the film is not drawn tight.